# How to get all the categories of a Woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

hello I want to develop a woo-commerce website and JSON API, I want to "get all categories for a product"

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( '1753', 'product_cat' );
//$nterms = get_the_terms( '1753', 'product_tag' );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
   $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
   $product_cat_name = $term->name;
   break;
}
```

Comment: Just add what you have tried for this.

Comment: terms = get_the_terms( '1753', 'product_cat' );
        $nterms = get_the_terms( '1753', 'product_tag'  );
        foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
            $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
            $product_cat_name = $term->name;
            break;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
<?php
get_the_term_list( '1753', 'product_cat', '', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

Check reference here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list